# Inserting code from child class method implementation in between code from parent class method implementation

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I am using inheritance to extract common behavior into my parent class. Here's my parent class BaseService :

```
class BaseService
  def initialize(data, failure_strategy)
    @data = data
    @failure_strategy = failure_strategy
  end

  def create
    return if associated_model.find_by(id: @data['id'])
    # insert specific code from child class CREATE method implementation here
  rescue => exception
    @failure_strategy.rescue(exception)
  end

  private

  def associated_model
    self.class.to_s.delete("EventsService").constantize
  end
end
```

Basically I am implementing different failure strategies in case of an exception occuring. However I would like the specific code from my child class implementation of `create` to be inserted in between two piece of code inside my parent class implementation of create...

```
return if associated_model.find_by(id: @data['id'])
        # insert specific code from child class CREATE method implementation here
      rescue => exception
        @failure_strategy.rescue(exception)
```

What is the right way to implement this kind of behavior in ruby ?

Comment: In `associated_model`, `self.class.to_s #=> "BaserService"`, so `"BaserService".delete("EventsService") #=>  "Ba"`. Is that what you want? Also, Ruby does not have a method `constantize`. I believe Rails has one, but there's no Rails tag. Lastly, there's no need for `"(Ruby)"` in the title since you have a "Ruby" tag.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this is indeed from a rails project. I deleted the ref to ruby in the title as suggested. The associated_model is supposed to be called in child classes. BaseService is actually an "abstract class" (even though there's no such thing in ruby), so I dont think this is a problem

Comment: I suggest you add a Rails tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the right way to implement this kind of behavior in ruby ?

Same as in any OOP language with classical inheritance: use the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

```
class BaseService

  def create
    return if associated_model.find_by(id: @data['id'])

    specific_create
  rescue => exception
    @failure_strategy.rescue(exception)
  end

  private

  def specific_create
    # default behaviour, possibly empty.
  end
end

class SpecificService < BaseService
  def specific_create
    # overridden behaviour
  end
end
```

---

> I see but my problem is that I want my method in the child class to be named create. What I'm looking for is some kind of reverse `super`, I guess.

This looks like something you can do with blocks.

```
class Parent
  def create
    puts "prep work"
    yield
  rescue => ex
    puts "error: #{ex}"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def create
    super do
      puts "specific work"
    end
  end
end

Child.new.create
# >> prep work
# >> specific work
```

Comment: I see but my problem is that I want my method in the child class to be named `create`...What Im looking for is some kind of reverse Super I guess. @SergioTulentsev Do you know if it's actually possible to do that ?

Comment: @DavidGeismar: check out the update. That's probably the best thing you can get :)

Comment: "Same as in any OOP language: behaviour override." – That is a very narrow view of "OOP language". Beta's prefix inheritance works exactly like the OP needs: instead of subclass method implementations calling superclass implementations, it is the other way around: the superclass methods leave "holes" in the implementation to be filled by subclass methods. So, it is exactly the other way around from classical inheritance: superclass methods call their subclass implementations. Note that mixin inheritances subsumes both classical and prefix inheritance. (See the Jigsaw paper.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: isn't that what I did here, though (in the first snippet)? Create a hole to be filled by descendant classes? (I should check that that paper, sounds interesting)

Comment: The OP wants a method with the same name that overrides the superclass method, and can then be called by the superclass method. That is exactly how prefix inheritance works and is more or less the opposite of how classical inheritance works. Your first sentence seems to imply that all OOP languages use classical inheritance, which is not the case. (In fact, some don't even have inheritance at all, whereas there are non-OOP languages that do have inheritance, even classical inheritance.) The *Template Method* Pattern you are using here is essentially a workaround for lack of prefix inheritance.

Comment: Perfect. Might make sense to include the words *Template Method Design Pattern* somewhere, since that's what it is. Also, "hook" and maybe "callback" (although the meaning of the latter seems to have shifted towards async programming in recent years).

Comment: It definitely is that. Forgot the formal name :)

Comment: `associated_model` seems to be [AWOL](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awol).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: was irrelevant, so I cut it out :shrug:

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I lost my buffer where I kept it and I was too lazy to go look it up. Thanks :)